# How to use "#pragma comment(lib, libname)" in programing C with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, visual-studio-code

When I wanted to learn socket programing in C with vscode, I found a guide. And I copied the code as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")  // Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;

    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Initialised.");

    return 0;
}
```

But when I wanted to run the code, I failed. Vscode's output is "warning: ignoring #pragma comment [-Wunknown-pragmas]"!
~My english is very poor, thank you for reading this question!~

Comment: Do you use mingw with VS code?

Comment: I use clang  instead of mingw.

Comment: To support Microsoft extensions clang has `-fms-extensions` command-line option. By default it's enabled, your code should work. Anyway try to add this option to clang command-line.

Comment: Still wrong！  `Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file`

Comment: `undefined reference to '__imp_WSAStartup'`  `undefined reference to '__imp_WSAGetLastError'`

Comment: No more `warning: ignoring #pragma comment` error, but can't find the imports. Looks like incompatible ws2_32.lib.