# Can't add "ws2_32.lib" in any way

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winapi

I'm beginning with socket programming in C++, and as a normal student, I went to search online.

The problem is, it doesn't matter what I do, I always get the following errors:

```
C:\Users\farin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQCkFqw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
C:\Users\farin\AppData\Local\Temp\ccQCkFqw.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x48): undefined reference to `WSAGetLastError@0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm using MinGW in Visual Studio Code.

Here's the sample code I've been messing around with:

```
/*
    Initialise Winsock
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("Initialised.");

    return 0;
}
```

I've already tried linking to the compiler, and possibly gone throught all the pages
about the subject that I could find.

Comment: Have you tried linking it on the command line? I don't know if MinGW works with that pragma as the Microsoft compiler does.

Comment: Yes, i did @RetiredNinja. Same issues D:

Comment: Can you show how you did that?

Comment: Exact duplicate, unanswered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66928815/how-to-use-pragma-commentlib-libname-in-programing-c-with-visual-studio-co You should get the warning: ignoring #pragma comment

Comment: `g++ -Iws2_32.lib main.cpp -o main.exe`  and without the .lib

Comment: Libraries need to come after the code that uses them on the command line. Move `-lws2_32` to the end of the command line. Note there's no extension.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja, it worked! omg ashamed that i didnt thought about that lmao. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here!

Just ran throught the command line, as follow:

```
g++  main.cpp -o main.exe -lws2_32
```

Thanks to Retired Ninja.